# What is the memory requirement for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I'm considering buying Aspire with 1 GB RAM which runs Windows 7 Home.  This site told me I could install Windows 10 on the stated model. Because of that, I almost bought the Aspire.  Will 1 GB RAM be sufficient to install Windows 10?

Comment: I've seen a PC with 1GB RAM which was running Windows 7, 8, 8.1 perfectly for years. Now, [new system specifications](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications#sysreqs) stayed the same as [Windows 8.1 specs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements) so it will be OK. Sidenote: If you see 100% disk usage when nothing happens (no archiving, no windows update) remember to turn off Superfetch service. That's the only headache I've seen so far.

Comment: The only caveat here is - if you have 1GB RAM, probably your CPU is old and it doesn't support [PAE,NX,SSE2](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-is-pae-nx-sse2), especially NX. So make sure your CPU supports them before buying that computer or Windows 10. Checking is easy, google "Intel ARK your_cpu_model_eg_i3-3220" and find there `Instruction Set Extensions` for SSE, and `Execute Disable Bit` for NX support.

Comment: Out of interest, what is this device that has only 1GB of RAM - is it a phone, or a decade or so old, or are there actually "PC class" devices being sold with such specs?

Comment: @Nye IT came with Win7 so it's almost certainly several years old.  OTOH budget Windows tablets are shipping with 1GB of ram today.

Comment: It will run, but I wouldn't want to use either Windows 7 or Windows 10 with just 1GB.

Comment: Why would you ask the same question twice?

Comment: Personal advice: New devices with 2 GB RAM are currently available for $150, new devices with 1 GB RAM start at $70. Laptops with 4GB RAM start at $200. They come with Windows 8 or 10, and a year of free Office 365/Onedrive/Skype. Unless the device is less than $50 and you actually like installing a new OS, I'd personally recommend against purchasing an ancient 1 GB machine.

Comment: If you've read first 2 comments, don't get ready to buy it. I highly recomend you to buy a better computer with at least 2GB RAM and 2GHz (dual-core at minimum). If you are running out of money, and you can't find/get a better one then don't forget to add another 5-10$ to add RAM. Otherwise forget about high-performance programs, usual gaming and so on, it will be useful only for home/office usage.

Answer (score 26):

It is enough for Windows 10 32-bit. You will need at least 2GB for Windows 10 64-bit though.

[image]

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications#sysreqs

Comment: While it does meet the minimum requirements, I would strongly urge anyone I liked to consider much more than 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence. I've updated a 1GB HP Stream 7 tablet from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. Runs fine for something that only cost £75 including Office 365.

Comment: @DavidMarshall Another evidence. I've never seen frozen HP Stream 7. But I think it has customized Windows because it was using 2GB disk space with Windows 8.

Comment: I am running Windows 10 32-bit on a netbook with 1 GB of RAM and it works fine. Yes, it's slow, but hardly any more so than it was with Windows 8 and Windows 7 starter before that.

Comment: @Jet It used WIMBoot in Windows 8 which runs off a compressed image.

Comment: Find out if your video driver has it's own ram. Some machines are set to use 256mb of system ram which leaves Windows 10 with 768mb, which is far too little. Video ram can sometimes be adjusted and lowered in the bios.

Comment: @DavidMarshall Please consider that in a flash based system, low memory might not be as noticeable as disk swapping is fast.  However, 1GB on a hard drive based system might be quite painful as others are indicating.  Your evidence isn't wrong, but you clearly have mitigating factors.

Comment: @AdamDavis That's undoutably true. It's not clear what the OP was looking at. There are Asus Aspire Switch with similar 32GB eMMC.

Comment: I purchased new laptop with 4GB RAM and i5 5th generation processor, and the speed of windows 10(preinstalled) is like windows Vista.. everything hangs at some point, very unresponsive..

Answer (score 19):

#### Windows 10 is designed to cope with low-memory devices.

- 1 GB of memory is sufficient to run Windows 10. In fact, it will likely perform better than Windows 7 because it is tuned to perform well on devices with very limited hardware such as low-cost tablets.

#### Adding more memory is ideal. Otherwise, use ReadyBoost.

- However, there's no getting around the fact that 1 GB of RAM is very low by today's standards. Even smartphones are available with 2 GB of memory or more. To make the most of your system, and assuming that adding more memory is not possible (not unlikely with cheap netbooks of this sort), you should consider using **[ReadyBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost)** to maximize performance.
- ReadyBoost uses flash memory devices such as USB flash drives or memory cards, taking advantage of their high random I/O performance, to speed up disk accesses for data that would otherwise be cached in memory on a machine with more RAM. If you have an unused media reader, get a high-speed SD card at least 4 GB in size, format it as exFAT, and use it to augment the system's low memory.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote here?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I actually had **worst** performance with my old computer when using ReadyBoost. USB devices and SD cards are really slow compared to a HDD. Specially the SD cards, which don't go any faster than a few Megabytes per second. Also, it causes high wear on the devices, which is bad.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel only if you try to use an unsuitable one. If you buy an SD card, flash drive or ssd that is certified for readyboost and are using it on a built-in card reader or usb3 then it will work well.

Comment: @JamesRyan Still, let me disagree with you. But if you buy an external SSD, you might just replace your HDD and you don't need to worry about ReadyBoost! I did tried to use suitable ones. It was an old Windows Vista PC with only 512MB RAM. Using the pendrive for ReadyBoost would kill the system. Stopping it would allow me to somewhat use it. I agree that an USB3 external UDB drive might work ok, but remember the overhead of the protocol.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: The Vista implementation of ReadyBoost wasn't great. ReadyBoost in Windows 7 and later does not experience the same issue due to improvements made to the technology. In addition, SD cards and flash drives are faster these days and you stand to get a visible gain in performance if you used ReadyBoost today on a low-RAM system.

Comment: @DragonLord I must test it at home. Windows 7, 128MB RAM, my trusty ReadyBoost URB 2.1 drives ready to be burned and hopefully I will be proven wrong. In this context, it's good to be proven wrong.

Comment: Readyboost isn't there to deal with low ram, it is there to deal with slow HDD speeds.  Flash is substantially faster.  How are you even testing with 128MB RAM, can you get modules that small on remotely modern hardware?  If it is some sort of virtual environment then it won't have direct access to the USB and introducing overheads that a real system doesn't have.

Comment: -1 ReadyBoost has nothing to do with low RAM.

Comment: @Mehrdad: How? ReadyBoost is designed precisely to improve performance on PCs with low memory. Normally, data from disk is cached in RAM. On a low-memory machine, there is less space to maintain this cache, so programs tend to open much slower, even if the system isn't paging to disk. ReadyBoost helps by using high-speed flash memory for disk caching.

Comment: @DragonLord: Yes but consider that it wouldn't make any difference if the pagefile was already on an SSD. It simply doesn't alleviate the low RAM problem. It just alleviates the low hard disk speed problem. If your program requires more RAM than is in your system, ReadyBoost won't help one bit either. It simply has nothing to do with RAM, even though as a *side effect* it happens to be occasionally helpful if you have low RAM.

Comment: I would rather disable (or set "manual-start") odd services which R/W on HDD e.g , Superfetch, Volume Shadow Copy, Automatic backups etc. They decrease both RAM (by using memory) and HDD (slower speed) performance. Also placing page-file on USB (3+) and ReadyBoost are good idea, that's a working workaround on slow machines (take upvote). Anyway though I have 2GB RAM, I disable all odd services/programs from autostart (e.g. Print Spooler, I don't have printer). The result is - normal Windows 7 which uses 300MB (!) RAM

Answer (score 9):

While technically it may be possible, your computer will run slower than a snail because 1GB RAM is technically nothing in this age for a PC. Even a Pentium 4 machine 10 years ago could have more RAM than that. Because of the lack of RAM, the page file will have to be constantly used, which is **very** slow. Even 2GB won't be enough.

Nowadays, with modern operating systems, you are strongly recommended to get a machine with at least 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Even if the OS will fit, it won't leave much RAM for multiple, concurrent apps, background programs, or programs that are memory hogs.  There are featherweight Linux distros that will run in practically no RAM, but 1GB isn't enough to accomplish much.

Comment: I disagree with the “Pentium 4 machine 10 years ago” thing. I had precisely that, a Pentium 4 machine bought before 2006, a relatively standard computer, and came with 768 MB of RAM.

Comment: Of course it can't be the same for everyone, just like right now there are i5 machines with 4GB of RAM and there are those with 16GB of RAM. What I mean to say is that even 10 years ago, a machine with > 1GB of RAM is not that uncommon.

Comment: It doesn't help that `ntoskrnl.exe` likes to be memory-hungry in Windows 10, sometimes using up to 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: `ntoskrnl.exe` can include third-party kernel-mode drivers.

Comment: @Chin I'm pretty skeptical of it being common, too. I have a 2005/2006 desktop with 1 GB of RAM. In 2005, Vista hadn't even come out yet and 64 bit was unusual for PCs; we're talking about the XP era. And it's not like Pentium 4 was necessarily the highest end thing at the time; they started producing those in 2000. At the time of Vista's release *2 years later*, the min system reqs are 512 GB for 32-bit, and I have a hard time believing vendors were regularly putting in more than about 1-2 GB at that time. XP's system reqs were only 256 MB. 512 MB-1 GB sounds like the norm for 2005.

Comment: You're right, 512-1GB is the norm in 2005. However, just about 1-2 years later, with the advance of 64 bit OSes (particularly Vista), the average suddenly jumps to about 2GB. I found this article http://techtalk.pcpitstop.com/2008/04/24/average-installed-memory-vista-vs-xp/ which basically says the same thing.

Comment: @Chin I wouldn't call that "sudden." It pretty closely follows Moore's Law, after all (double the power in 2 years.). And that's only 8 years ago. ;)

Comment: Your answer doesn't contain anything specific to Windows 10.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: re: `ntoskrnl.exe` using 1GB of RAM: this is not the actual system+driver memory use, but is instead due to the fact that Windows 10 does memory compression and any compressed memory pages are stored in ntoskrnl.exe's memory space.

Answer (score 8):

**tl;dr: It will run, and performance can be acceptable. With default settings, performance will not be acceptable.**

I'm actually running Windows 10 on a 1 GB RAM device (small tablet). It came with Windows 8.1 and was eligible for the free upgrade. Whenever the device runs out of RAM, the device becomes unresponsive for 30-300 seconds.

This happened often if I had Windows Update, Windows Defender, and any browser running at the same time. To avoid RAM from becoming a constant issue, all I had to do was disable Windows Defender, which is the biggest memory hog on a 1 GB machine, using 0.2-0.3 GB. On the basic Windows 10 version, the only way to do that is with a registry entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender
DisableAntiSpyware DWORD
0 = On
1 = Off
```

On the Pro and Enterprise versions it can be disabled with a group policy. See here: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5918-windows-defender-turn-off-windows-10-a.html#option2

With Windows Defender disabled my 1 GB device doesn't have any issues running light tasks like webbrowsing with ~10 open tabs, with IE, or Edge, or Mozilla, or Chrome. I tested some other antivirus software and they trigger the same issue. If you are not comfortable running without antivirus, I'd advise to buy a 2-4 GB RAM machine instead.

Also keep in mind 2GB RAM does not mean there's twice the amount of RAM available for your applications. Various services on the device will already use up to around 500 MB of your RAM, so on a 1 GB device your applications can only really use about 500 MB. With a 2 GB machine, your applications can use 1.5 GB. These are not hard numbers. Some services such as Windows Update won't run all the time, other services may only be introduced with an update in a year from now, others might be removed a year from now, and others again are linked to the audio drivers of your device.

Since this may be relevant to some readers: The OS uses almost exactly 10 GB as of August 2015, and is expected to grow. This is after using Disk Cleanup to delete the recovery partition and remove the backup of Windows 8.1, which is created when installing Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

It will run, but performance will be terrible.

It so happens that I have a VMWare image I used for testing the early access versions that's now updated to the release version, so I throttled it back to 1GB of RAM to see what that looks like:

[image: Memory usage after startup]

Note that it's already swapping.

(Update: performance is so bad that just navigating to the shutdown menu was painful.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mechanical hard drive, then 1GB will appear to be slow.  It'll run, and if you run only one or two low-end apps at once, you'll be fine, but try to open a lot of tabs in a browser window or look at huge documents and spreadsheets and you may be frustrated by lagging.

If the computer is using an SSD, though, then the low memory will be mitigated by fast swap space on the solid state hard drive, and you will have much more headroom to run memory intensive apps.

Ready boost may be a decent work around if you have a mechanical hard drive and 1GB RAM.  Insert a low profile but fast flash drive into a USB port, tell windows to use readyboost on it, and you may be happy with the performance.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to stress that the 32bit Versions of OSes are significantly different from the 64 bit versions because their binaries are significantly smaller both in size and actual execution footprint. Therefore if you use a 32bit version of Windows 10, you will have much better chances on an older PC with low memory that can barely run the 64bit version. It's significant to point out that this is not because of the current third party application you will be running but predominately because the whole-OS binaries collection will need lower resources usage, including drive reading usage.

PS. Linux has a special kernel version that runs on 64bit instructions but the entire rest of the OS is on 32bit binaries. That is a good middle ground. Of course it will always be a niche because most people will either have a fast-enough machine for 64bit OSes or one that will not get significant gains compared to purely 32bit.

Answer (score -1):

It's technically possible, but experience has told me that 1 GB of memory is insufficient for present proposes, only using a web browser with applications like Facebook, [Google Docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Docs,_Sheets,_and_Slides), YouTube, etc. can gather all the memory, making the system slow.

Comment: It's technically possible to run Firefox with your applications with 1GB RAM. But I don't want to talk about Chrome...

Comment: I mean to say that you'll probably use a web browser and others. And probably it consume all the resources

Comment: @Jet I tried. Surprisingly, there's no problem whatsoever.

Comment: I have a netbook with 1GB RAM and it cannot run Google Docs on Chrome without lag

Comment: @Nerol Right now I'm writing from Firefox with ~20 open tabs + QT Creator; still runs smoothly (on 1GB RAM, Windows 7). But I agree it may be impossible to do the same with Chrome (especially with newer versions).

Comment: @Jet I'm impress, but if you said that I believe you. Maybe the problem is the whole of my netbook, including CPU, RAM speed, etc

Comment: You just mentioned one important thing - RAM speed. Also I would add HDD speed (for page-file). If RAM and HDD speed are fast, then 1GB RAM doesn't seem so bad for home usage. But if it's slow DDR2 and old HDD, that's just... Anyway If my computer/notebook had 1GB RAM I would add another 1GB and will not regret these 5-10$ to save me from annoyance